# confidence interval for conditional probabilities

Tags: conditional-statements, probability, confidence-interval

is there a possibility to create a confidence interval for conditional probabilities? I found some formula to create a CI for probabilities, but not for this special case.

Answer (score 1):

## Confidence Intervals

I think you mean a **confidence interval** for **a random variable**. For example, if I have a continuous real-valued random variable X, I could say something like

P(a <= X <= b) = 0.95

meaning I am 95% confident that X is between a and b.

## Conditional Confidence Intervals

A ***conditional* confidence interval** would be a statement like

P(a <= X <= b | Y = y) = 0.95

meaning, ***when Y is y,*** I am 95% confident that X is between a and b, where Y is some other random variable.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this does not exactly describe my problem. I'll explain it in anotherway:

Comment: I have a variable a and a variable b. Both variables are factors with four choices (states). I builded a multinomial logistical regression to predict conditional probabilities. Now I get 16 probabilities. What I would like to have as result, is a confidence interval of these conditional probabilities. That means 16 upper and lower boarders. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Not enough details to tell. Update your question.